# Acumatica Configuration Wizard error: Can't get IIS Version on registry

Tags: acumatica

I tried to create a new instance on Acumatica Configuration Wizard. I get an error that says **"Can't get your IIS version from the registry."** although I already installed the IIS feature. I followed the instructions on what feature to install on the IIS. .net framework it uses is 4.6.

[image: IIS Installed feature]

[image: Acumatica Config error]

Comment: try running the configuration wizard as Administrator.

Comment: i still get same error.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this problem still hasn't been fixed. And the suggested solution is not correct.

The key to this problem is here: Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey

They are using the Remote Registry service in Windows to talk to the registry. However, the remote registry service has to be enabled on the computer before this is allowed.

Why aren't they just calling the registry locally? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registry.getvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2

Beats me...

To enable the Remote Registry Service, go to Services Manager in Windows, find Remote Registry Service, right-click and select Properties, then Enable the service in the control panel. Then, right click the service and Start it. Problem will be solved and you will be able to proceed with Acumatica installation.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution! At the time when this was reported I wasn't able to resolve this even turning it on and off the IIS didn't work. Though as far I could remember the environment have wamp installed, and we thought it had conflicted with the configuration of the IIS thus unable to detect the IIS. So we transferred to another server without wamp and the IIS worked.

So for now, I can't validate your proposed solution as I haven't encountered this problem again. Though I'll take note of this in case I encounter such error again.

Answer (score 0):

The registry path checked by the wizard is:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\InetStp
```

Make sure at least 'MajorVersion' key exist and have proper access rights:
[image]

As a last resort, you can try creating the register folders path and 'MajorVersion' key manually if need be, make sure 'MajorVersion' field type is REG_DWORD. Your version number can be shown in menu Help->About of IIS Manager 'inetmgr.exe':
[image]