# Acumatica Configuration Error: Network Path Cannot Be Found

Tags: acumatica

This most likely a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34079404/203857), but it doesn't seem like that one has much traction.  Hoping this does.

I'm running a Windows 10 machine and trying to get setup to start doing the Acumatica university and I'm having difficulty with the configuration wizard.  Everything installs fine.  I have IIS installed and enabled.  But when it gets to step 5 of 8 I get an unhandled exception error saying "Network path cannot be found".  If I drill into the details and look at the stack trace it appears it's looking for something in the registry.

Here's a snippet:

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.IO.IOException: The network path was not found.

   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.Win32ErrorStatic(Int32 errorCode, String str)
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive hKey, String machineName, RegistryView view)
   at ConfigCore.RemoteResourceLocator.OpenSubKeyLocalMachine(String strSubKey, Boolean rw)
   at ConfigCore.IISInstalled.GetSitesList()
```

If I click continue, fill in the path and then click continue, I get this error:
"Сan't get your IIS version from the registry. Probably you don't have IIS?"

Again looking at the stacktrace, I see this:

```
 at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.Win32ErrorStatic(Int32 errorCode, String str)
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive hKey, String machineName, RegistryView view)
   at ConfigCore.RemoteResourceLocator.OpenSubKeyLocalMachine(String strSubKey, Boolean rw)
   at ConfigCore.IISInstalled.get_Version()
```

Comment: I posted an answer here but it was deleted by moderators. Look at the question you linked to, it contains part of the solution. The two package you want to install from Acumatica: 'AcumaticaERPInstall.msi' and 'AcumaticaFrameworkInstall.msi' .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the advice from the referenced question as well as the recommendation from HB_ACUMATICA, I ran the configuration utility as admin, but wasn't getting any luck. I know it has something to do with permissions, but I ultimately reset my machine, tried again and it worked this time around.  Would be nice to know what the core root of the problem was, but I'm satisfied enough that it's working now.